# Need to get value in the result of loopin through all bars checking its RSI

Tags: arrays, loops, pine-script

**How to loop through all bars I have on the graphic and check its RSI?**

[image: The green line is a result of my script]

**Code:**

```
sum = 0
if ta.rsi(close, 7) >= 80
    sum += 5
else if ta.rsi(close, 7) <= 60
    sum -= 5
plot(sum, color=color.green)
```

It's not working correctly, because on each new bar the sum value sets back to 0. My goal is to see on my graphic the line which increases or decreases in the result of the `if` statement.

Comment: Have you tried something or are you asking us to write the code for you? Your script will be ececuted for each bar starting from the beginning. So, you don’t need an actual loop for your purpose.

Comment: can you check the message below, please?

Comment: No. Don't use the answers section for updates on the question. It is meant to actually ***answer*** the question. You can simply [edit] your question (which someone already did for you, just approve their edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `var` keyword.

> var is the keyword used for assigning and one-time initializing of the
> variable.

```
var sum = 0
if ta.rsi(close, 7) >= 80
    sum := sum + 5
else if ta.rsi(close, 7) <= 60
    sum := sum - 5
plot(sum, color=color.green)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's what i was looking for